# Is there a way to use an "ostream" to write over an existing instance of std::string

Tags: c++

I know all kinds of ostreams holds their own internal buffers.
I have to know whether there is some kind of ostream which accept an instance std::string and write on that instance.

(I want to avoid redundant copies)

**Note:** My question is about the standard library, don't offer me other libraries that can do that, I know they exist. :)

**Edit:** After a request to be more specific ... Here is what I want, consider the following code:

```
std::string str = "bla bla bla ";
std::ospecialstream o(str);
o << 34 << " bla bla";
std::cout << str; //console output : "bla bla bla 34 bla bla"
```

I want ospecialstream such that it won't copy str contents into some internal buffer but rather write to the same instance of str.

**Edit #2**
I need it for performece reasons , ostringstream will make a memcopy when created with a string and will also make a memcpy when the contents are retrieved.

Comment: I seriously doubt that that will fix any performance problems you might have. It's premature optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking can you alter the buffering of ostreams, then the answer is yes. However, depending on what you actually want the buffer to do,  this is not a particularly simple task. You will want to consult a book like [Langer & Kreft](http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html) for more info.

L&K have an example of how to implement an unbuffered output stream - it begins on page 229 of the book. It's too long to reproduce here, but basically you need to redefine the overflow() method of a derived streambuf class.

Note the book is not available on-line but the source code apparently is - see this [page](http://www.angelikalanger.com/IOStreams/examples.htm) for details.

Comment: I'll refer to that book , I guess I can consider your post a good answer , +1 , thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/) part of `sstream` header.

How about this:

```
void appendStuff(string& in) {
   ostringstream os;
   os << 34 << " bla bla";
   in += os.str();
}
```

Comment: ostringstream holds its own stringbuf.

Comment: @Pontus Gagge: Yes, of course it does. IMO this is what the OP wants.

Comment: That doesn't help for two reason . I want an ostream that will be built upon a predefined string.
Another problem is that when I want to retrieve the string from ostringstream , it will give me another copy.

Comment: @dirkgently: well, not what the OP asked for, but I agree that it's what's needed (rather than hacking around inside an exsting std::string).

Comment: @yossi1981: Since this is a very specific requirement (no copies), you will probably have to roll your own. I'd still go with ostringstream (is the copy the only binding factor?)

Comment: copy is the only thing that disturb me , my profiler shows me that  ostringstream is a bad boy , I assume that this is because it holds its internal data , I can improve the performence simply if i had that special ostream.

Comment: I'm referening to your edited post: that resolve one copy but I Have to problems with it, one is that when the str is retrieved from the os there is a copy and the second one is that will require me to change many places in the code , I still may consider your solution though, +1 for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: Yes, but this requires writing your own `streambuf` class, which you then set with `rdbuf`. Also, now deprecated [strstream](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/leif/sourcepro/html/stdlibref/strstream.html) does almost what you want and may still be in your compiler libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class intostring : public std::basic_streambuf<char> {
  std::string &str;
public:
  intostring(std::string &pstr):str(pstr) {}
  virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *const p, const std::streamsize n) {
    str.append(p, n);  
  }
};

int main() {
  std::string s("Original string: ");

  intostring newbuf(s);

  std::streambuf *oldbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(&newbuf);
  std::cout << "Should go to string" << std::endl;
  std::cout.rdbuf(oldbuf);  

  std::cout << "Should go to console again ... and here's the string: '" 
            << s << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

Should go to console again ... and here's the string: 'Original string: Should go to string'